# NodeJS OpenShift App times out on https, but not http

Tags: node.js, ssl, openshift

I've got a fairly simple app deployed on OpenShift that uses CloudFlare as a DNS provider, since they support CNAME records for the root domain, which our current domain provider does not.

The issue with this setup is somewhere along the line https is not working. I believe this is an OpenShift issue because it's the same kind of issue you get when you've mapped the domain name to your app but haven't added the proper aliases yet - you get a timeout essentially.

We've got two aliases - with www and without. There's no option to specify https or anything with OpenShift aliases from what I can see. There aren't any SSL certificates assigned to these aliases as we do not need or use https - we're on the Free plan.

The main URL to access the site is http://www.jcuri.com - notice this works as expected, however https://www.jcuri.com times out.

Initially we were thinking of using CloudFlare page rules to auto-redirect to a non-https URL however this is locked down behind a paywall which we're hoping to avoid, as we don't need any of the Pro features.

Is there something I'm missing here? It seems that OpenShift is just denying any https connections purely because we don't have certificates assigned to the aliases. I wouldn't even mind if there were certificate errors, at least that would give us a chance to do a redirect on the actual NodeJS application, but we don't even reach that point.

Can anyone offer some advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since those domains are not pointed directly at openshift via CNAME, but are seemingly redirected via another service (from what i can tell from the dns) it is hard to say whether it is OpenShift that is causing the https issues.  If you do not have a custom ssl certificate installed on openshift, you will just get an invalid certificate error, but since you are using a redirect service, maybe it is possible that the service is checking the certificate first, seeing an error, and then not working?

Since the https page rules you stated above are behind a paywall, this actually makes a lot of sense that they are blocking it, not OpenShift.  Godaddy provided a forwarding service that would allow you to point both www and naked domain to openshift correctly using cnames, i have used it before.

Comment: Yeah CloudFlare provide this forwarding service which is what I'm using to map the root domain and www to my OpenShift instance. I could only think of two things that are actually blocking it - the OpenShift instance not recognizing the HTTPS URL as a valid alias and timing out, or CloudFlare actively blocking secure connections without the Pro plan. I'm not really sure if there's any way I can investigate OpenShift though, my access logs show no attempts to connect at all from HTTPS.

Comment: It's not OpenShift blocking it, i have not had any issues.

Comment: Yup, CloudFlare's confirmed they're blocking it. Guess I'll transfer to Godaddy!